# differential quotient in Sobolev space by Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am studying Michiel's PDE book. Here I have a question about one theorem in chapter about Sobolev space.

At the beginning of this chapter, he define $\tau_y(u)(x)=u(x+y)$ and by assuming $u\in H^s(R^N)$, he conclude without the prove that 
$$\sigma^{-1}(\tau_{e_j\sigma}u(x)-u(x))\to i\partial_j u \text{ in }H^{s-1}$$
However, I did the calculation myself and I keep getting 
$$\sigma^{-1}(\tau_{e_j\sigma}u(x)-u(x))\to \partial_j u \text{ in }H^{s-1}$$
i.e., without $i$ in front of $\partial_j u$. I think my result, intuitively, true.(as the sense in classical approach) However, he repeat this result several times so I don't think this is just a typo... So can anybody explain me how this $i$ come from?

Thx!

Comment: Your result is correct, **unless** the author defines $\partial_j$ as $1/i \cdot D_j$, where $D_j$ denotes the "ordinary partial derivative". This convention is sometimes used in connection with the Fourier transform.

Comment: It makes sense. Thx!